# Fix #tag inurl for a AngularJS website?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, seo

Currently my website url is like this:

> example.com/#/services

required new url:

> example.com/services

i.e, I don't want the # tag in the website url.

Can anyone describe how I should fix this url issue - which file I have edit or check to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In your app config or router module, inject $locationProvider and configure for html5 mode.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```